# Trouble pathing an audio file using WMPLib

Tags: c#, path, wmplib

I'm new to C# and pathing files have troubled me for a while.

The file structure to the audio files is as follows:

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\Program\Form\WindowsFormApp\Audio Files\name.mp3
```

My visual studio forms are in:

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\Program\Form\WindowsFormApp
```

I tried referencing audio files by using the following URL:

```
soundplayer.URL = @"Audio Files\name.mp3";
```

However, that did not work.

I then placed the folder Audio Files inside practically every other folder. It still did not work.

I tried:

```
soundplayer.URL = @"..\\Audio Files\name.mp3";
```

That did not work as well. I cannot simply do the entire path of the audio because it is different on each computer.

How do I path this correctly?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how I can use StartUpPath to connect to my issue?

Comment: Always use full path names, c:\foo\bar\baz.ext, never baz.ext or bar\baz.ext.  The property I linked to gives you the c:\foo part, you just need to combine it with the relative path to the file.  Use Path.Combine().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, in your case, it would be as follows

```
using System.IO;
using WMPLib;

WindowsMediaPlayer player;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Audio Files\name.mp3");
 player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
 player.URL = fileInfo.Name;
 player.controls.play();
}
```

Where

```
//This function gets the current route of your project and combines it with the subfolder path where your music file is
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Audio Files\name.mp3");
```

Comment: That is my problem. I cannot reference `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Program\Form\WindowsFormApp\Audio Files\name.mp3` because that would only work on my computer. I need it to work on any computer.

Comment: @BrandonLiu This function gets the current route of your project and combines it with the subfolder path where your music file is

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!